beamer overlayarea preserve prior figure underneath with shading
Unfortunately, I had to fix some slides in a beamer presentation... I open a very similar post here.
However, my problem is now that I need both images and text in the same slide at the same location/position; the image and the text will change at every slide, so I thought about a very straightforward overlayarea + only which is, indeed, providing the expected result.
Still, I wish to have only the image of the first slide underneath the one in the second (but not the third) and grayed-out, but I'm not able to achieve so with an approach similar to one in the original post, nor I'm sure I'm approaching the problem correctly. Below a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\ifnum\c@framenumber>1%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=-2pt]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=\beamerheadheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frametitle{Properties and features:}
\framesubtitle<1>{paths,}
\framesubtitle<2>{paths, walks}
\framesubtitle<3>{paths, walks and SNARLs}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.95\textheight}

\only<1>{
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \vskip .2in
    \begin{exampleblock}{Paths}
        \centering an uninterrupted sequence of nodes and edges
    \end{exampleblock}
}

\only<2>{
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \vskip .2in
    \begin{exampleblock}{Walks}
        \centering an entire pangenome graph transversal that is, when from a start node a path gets across the graph – embodies the biological concept of \textit{haplotype}
    \end{exampleblock}
}

\only<3>{
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
    \vskip .2in
    \begin{alertblock}{Concept}
        \centering A \textbf{SNARL} is a polymorphic region, the graph-aware concept of a genetic locus or a \say{site}
    \end{alertblock}
}
\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
EDIT
I think I figured out a hack, but I'm not sure whether it's the only way or it's even optimal... below a MWE. If there is a way to do so without having to resort to changing the shade level, I will be very happy to learn about it!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\ifnum\c@framenumber>1%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=-2pt]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=\beamerheadheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\tikzset{%
    opinvisible/.style={opacity=0.75}, % -> changed this from .2 so that the image on the second slide gets the overlay from the first for the main part and only the differences are shaded
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{opinvisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paths, Walks and SNARLs}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0in]
\node<1-2>[visible on=<1>]
 {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};

\node<2>[visible on=<1>]
 {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}};

\node<3>[visible on=<3>]
 {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\only<1>{\begin{exampleblock}{Paths}
    \centering an uninterrupted sequence of nodes and edges
\end{exampleblock}}

\only<2>{\begin{exampleblock}{Walks}
    \centering an entire pangenome graph transversal that is, when from a start node a path gets across the graph – embodies the biological concept of \textit{haplotype}
\end{exampleblock}}

\only<3>{\begin{alertblock}{Concept}
    \centering A \textbf{SNARL} is a polymorphic region, the graph-aware concept of a genetic locus or a \say{site}
\end{alertblock}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

